# How to group these base on same address?

Tags: python, django

```
{'street_number': '3', 'street_name': 'Raycraft', 'street_type': 'Dr', 'municipality': 'Amherstview', 'postal_code': 'K7N1Z1', 'type_of_reports': 'Valuation'},
{'street_number': '3', 'street_name': 'Raycraft', 'street_type': 'Dr', 'municipality': 'Amherstview', 'postal_code': 'K7N1Z1', 'type_of_reports': 'Inspection'}
```

Group these values by address ?

for example output should be like:

```
{'street_number': '3', 'street_name': 'Raycraft', 'street_type': 'Dr', 'municipality': 'Amherstview', 'postal_code': 'K7N1Z1', 'type_of_reports': ['Valuation',Inspection]}
```

Comment: I dont understand the question. Also, is this a dictionary? json? xlm?

Comment: it is a queryset for django. i need to convert it like in another format.

Comment: I dont understand the difference between the set and expected output.

Comment: type of reports are coming together

Answer (score 0):

I assume each of those keys is a field name in a model somewhere. If you want to do this directly in the template you might be able to use [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

In your model add a property that is a string of all the info you want to group on:

```
@cached_property
def id_str(self):
    return f'{self.street_number} {self.street_name}, {self...}'#add all fields you wish to group by
```

Then in your view add a queryset of the model to the context and in the template regroup on this property (assume the context object is called queryset):

```
{% regroup queryset by id_str as regrouped_queryset %}
<ul>
  {% for address in regrouped_queryset %}
    <li>{{ address.grouper }}</li>
      <ul>
        {% for each in address.list %}
          <li>{{ each.type_of_reports }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: i tried your but it is not giving as output seems.

Comment: What was the output?